# How to restore nuget packages from network share in Linux Docker container

Tags: linux, docker, .net-core, ravendb, dotnet-restore

I'm tring to build a .NET Core solution in a Docker container but cannot get the `dotnet restore` command to work. I need to use both a local network share (just a simple filesystem repository) as well as the official nuget repo.

My nuget config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="Nuget Feed" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="custom feed" value="//uvd-fs1.uvd.local/Install/UVPackages" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

I start the container using the command `docker run -it --rm -v "$pwd\:/sln" microsoft/aspnetcore-build:latest`

Then `cd sln` and `dotnet restore ./UVAudit.sln`.

This produces the following error:

```
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/1.0.1/NuGet.targets(97,5): error : Failed to retrieve information about 'RavenDB.Client' from remote source '/uvd-fs1.uvd.local/Install/UVPackages'. [/sln/UVAudit.sln]
```

I would expect the RavenDB package to be restored from the official feed, but if I remove the custom package source from the nuget.config file, only the non-official packages cannot be resolved. This makes me think that the error message is a bit misleading. I would also think that the `/uvd-fs1.uvd.local/Install/UVPackages` part should in fact be `//uvd-fs1.uvd.local/Install/UVPackages`, but adding further slashes does nothing. Any ideas if I'm doing something wrong or this looks like a bug? I'm no Linux expert, so I might be missing some basic concept.

I also tried changing the repository path to `smb://uvd-fs1.uvd.local/Install/UVPackages` which caused the error message to change to:

```
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/1.0.1/NuGet.targets(97,5): error : Failed to verify the root directory of local source 'smb://uvd-fs1.uvd.local/Install/UVPackages'. [/sln/UVAudit.sln]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/1.0.1/NuGet.targets(97,5): error :   smb://uvd-fs1.uvd.local/Install/UVPackages [/sln/UVAudit.sln]
```

I don't really know if this even makes sense to try, just one of the very limited clues provided by googling.

Comment: Btw, my machine is running Windows 10 with Docker For Windows if it has any relevance.

Comment: What if you change uvd-fs1.uvd.local to the IP Address instead? The container may not be able to resolve the name.

Comment: That didn't change anything. I also made sure that I could ping the network path from the container.

Answer (score 1):

UNC paths (`\\..`) are primarily a windows concept. While the underlying protocol for network und paths is smb, the NuGet client won't support it - the reason it works on windows is because the file system api handles UNC paths transparently.

If you want to restore reliably from a docker container, i suggest setting up a NuGet feed (there is a NuGet.Server nuget package for asp.net websites which is sufficient for small internal feeds).